# cloud functions - access json like object values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using cloud firestore and cloud functions. I have a function which listens to when something is written to a particular path in the cloud firestore database, and it does something `onWrite()`. In particular, I am implementing stripe payments. I have a number of fields written to the database, one being an object, which is structured like (output of console logging the payment object):

```
{ payment: { amount: 500, token: { card: [Object], ...} } }
```

When I try and do the following, in particular the console.log():

```
exports.charge = functions.firestore
  .document('/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const payment = change.after.data();
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;

    console.log(payment.amount + " " + userId + " " + paymentId);
 })
```

When console logging payment.amount, it is displayed as `undefined`.

How can I access the amount value correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I see your mistake, if I'm understanding your structure correctly.

```
const data = change.after.data();
const payment = data.payment;
console.log(payment.amount + " " + userId + " " + paymentId);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I realise now I wasn't actually accessing the payment object in the first place.